Evince bookmarks issue
After many years (almost twenty) I went back to Linux and I was looking for a good PDF reader that also has a minimum of editing options (highlighter, notes, bookmark).
So I spotted evince (v45) but it causes me problems with bookmarks.
Searching on their website I found this issue.
After I read this post I had a doubt, how can I have the bookmarks
on another PC (which may not be Linux) when I share the PDF?
